# DataGrid with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to use this code to display on the grid where information is researched according to the previously marked field

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE setor ='" + TxtPesq.Text + "'"
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(myData)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = myData
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Please provide more detail.

Comment: Hi, Can u check data is comming in mydata object...?

Answer (score 0):

- use `using` statement for proper disposal of objects.
- parameterized your query to avoid sql injection

full code

```
Dim dSet As New Dataset
Dim SQL AS String= "SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE setor = @setor"
Using conn As New MySqlConnection("connectionStr HERE")
    Using myCommand As New MysqlCommand()
        With MyCommand
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = SQL
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@setor", TxtPesq.Text) 
        End With
        Using myAdapter As New MySQLDataAdapter(myCommand)
            Try
                myAdapter.Fill(dset)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dset.tables(0)
            Catch(ex as MySQLException)
                Msgbox (ex.Messge)
            End Try
        End Using
    ENd Using
ENd Using
```